# Check if a URL in anchor tag exists on a page on remote URL

Tags: php

My project requires a free user to put a URL to project site on their website to get SEO and back links for project site. So I want to check if

`<a href='http://examplesite.com'>example site</a>`

exists on page specified by URL given by registering user.
I would have to use this check multiple times so want a less  resource hungry solution.

Comment: even If I do use CURL what should I do to check if anchor link exists to my  project site? For now I am just checking for href="http://site.com" in retrieved contents which is not a reliable solution. I want a better solution.

Comment: but what would that solution look like? How else can you check for the presence of a link in a HTML page if you don't actually *fetch* the HTML page?

Comment: I want something similar to a REGEX check. If user puts either <a href='site.com'> site name </a> or <a class='someclass' href='site.com'>site name</a> or any other valid anchor tag, it should all be considered valid!

Comment: and yeh I don't mind fetching the HTML page.

Comment: but that does have nothing to do with whether you use curl or not, does it? You will have to fetch the page in any case.

Comment: Either you load the html of the page with curl or file_get_contents or whatever and then you setup a regular expression that checks for the required link in the retrieved html source. There is no other (easier) method.

Comment: exactly! so I edited question to remove CURL, now propose solution to check whether an anchor tag "<a href='http://www.mysite.com'>My Site</a>" exists in a FETCHED page content.

Comment: So what should be that REGEX like?

Comment: $regex = "/<a href=(\"|')http://(www.)?yoursite\.com(.*)?(\"|')
preg_match( $regex , $bodyhtml , $matches );
something like this - not tested; you can make it more complex, checking what is between the <a></a> tags, but that is completely up to you..

Comment: Thanks Luceos, yours is first logical answer to what I am looking for.  Check my question, I edited it to put the function that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. This function did what I wanted:

```
function checkurl($url, $urltocheckfor){
    $input = @file_get_contents($url);
    $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches)) {
        if(in_array($urltocheckfor))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think curl is *that* much more resource hungry (if at all) than using some other PHP function to fetch the remote resource - they all use the same basic principles.

But [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is a viable alternative if curl isn't available. You can use the new [stream contexts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to mimick most of curl's capabilities like sending an appropriate `user-agent` header, etc.

Comment: but CURL's not a problem here what I am asking for is a way to check if the retrieved page contains "<a href='site.com'> anything </a>"

Comment: @codefreak the way to check is to 1. fetch the HTML page and 2. look whether the content is there. What other method are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code resource wise.

```
// Initializes a new session and return a cURL handle
$handle = curl_init($url);

// Sets an option on the given cURL session handle
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// Execute the given cURL session
$response = curl_exec($handle);

// Gets information about the last transfer.
// CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE - Last received HTTP code 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($httpCode == 404) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // your code here
}

curl_close($handle);
```

Comment: using CURL or not using it isn't a problem, I just want to check if anchor tag such as "<a href='http://mysite.com'>My Site</a>" exists on page at URL given by registering user.